# logging libraries for visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010

I was using log4net for Visual Studio 2005. However, I am now using visual studio 2010.

log4net is not available for that framework.

Is there any other logging libraries out there that I can use?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, the IDE isn't really a factor here.  That said, use [Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with log4Net, it may be as simple as changing your application's target framework.  See this post that describes how the author was able to get log4Net up and running: http://krishnabhargav.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-net-35-clr-20-dll-inside-visual.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, it doesn't have to be log4net, I can use any other logging libraries that are available. Thanks.